# move string vector to another string vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, int

I am trying to move elements in a string vector to another string vector. At the moment I have found a solution but it's only for a integer vector. I know there are obvious changes to be made like the vector but I'm struggling to figure out what else I should change. Below is the code that is used to move a integer vector to another integer vector.

```
int main() 
{ 
    std :: vector <int> vec1 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    std :: vector <int> vec2 {7, 7, 7, 7, 7}; 

    // Print elements 
    std :: cout << "Vector1 contains :"; 
    for(int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) 
        std :: cout << " " << vec1[i]; 
    std :: cout << "\n"; 

    // Print elements 
    std :: cout << "Vector2 contains :"; 
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec2.size(); i++) 
        std :: cout << " " << vec2[i]; 
    std :: cout << "\n\n"; 

    // std :: move function 
    // move first 4 element from vec1 to starting position of vec2 
    std :: move (vec1.begin(), vec1.begin() + 4, vec2.begin() + 1); 

    // Print elements 
    std :: cout << "Vector2 contains after std::move function:"; 
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec2.size(); i++) 
        std :: cout << " " << vec2[i]; 
    std :: cout << "\n";
```

Comment: You have `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::vector<char>` or simple `std::string` ?

Comment: yes I know I can change that but I have to also change the for loops but I'm unsure what to replace them with

Comment: Why do you have to change the for loops? I don't see why (and in any case the for loops are only printing the results, they've got nothing to do with moving one vector to another).

Comment: If I understand what you want to do correctly, you don't have to change anything (other than the vectors), see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zve8bOApXP1ep6eu

Comment: Here's a hint, instead of posting the code that you think works, post the code that you think doesn't work. You'll get more useful help that way.

Comment: the code that I posted does actually work I tested it

Comment: That's good, but it still doesn't change the fact that it would be easier to help you with the code that doesn't work if you posted that code. It's a very common problem in the forum, beginners seem reluctant to show their failed attempts at writing code (embarassment I guess) but that's exactly what needed to pinpoint what their misunderstanding is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong even for an integer vector, try this.

```
std::move(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin());
```

It also has the problem that it assumes that the destination vector `vec2` is large enough to recieve the contents of the source vector `vec1`. Better code would be to resize `vec2` to be the same size as `vec1` before doing the move

```
vec2.resize(vec1.size());
std::move(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin());
```

That said there no reason than any of the code will not work with other kinds of vector. What problems are you seeing with other vectors?